# iPhone - Core Data : forgetting object

Tags: iphone

I am inserting new entries to a core data entity using this

```
newEntry = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"myEntity" inManagedObjectContext:context];
```

after that, I populate newEntry properties but at some point, and before this newEntry is saved to the context, I may want to remove this newEntry from the "buffer" or whatever, so it will not be saved when I commit the changes.

How do I do that? I have tried to use reset and rollback but it had no effect and the object continues to be saved.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[context deleteObject:newEntry];
```

This will remove it from the context.

[More information and sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Articles/06_Deleting.html)